# when i try to insert the below query but error while inserting to table why?

Tags: .net

When I try to insert the below query but error while inserting to table why?

```
protected void Btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string s = Drptype.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string b = "select STYPE_ID from suppliertype where stype_name = Drptype.SelectedItem.ToString()";
            string id = condb.scalar(b);
            string c = "insert into supplier(sup_name,sup_typid,sup_add,sup_gst) values ('" + Txtname.Text + "'," + id + ",'" + txtadd.Text + "','" + Txtgst.Text + "')";
            bool b1 = condb.dbins(c);
            if (b1== true)
            {
                RegisterStartupScript("", "<script Langauge=JavaScript>alert('Saved Successfully')</Script>");
            }
            else
            {
                RegisterStartupScript("", "<script Langauge=JavaScript>alert('Failed to save')</Script>");
            }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, please use parameterised queries.

Comment: Not the question, but `Langauge` will not work.